# Refresh all DataGrids with event handler

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling

I have a MainWindow, this containing a menu, that menu opens different windows. Each window with a list can open other windows to edit the data. I need when saved in one of these forms or remove an entity, trigger some event and all other screens receive the event to refresh the controls or DataGrids. Example:

I have open three windows, one is ProductList, this window have a DataGrid of Products with two columns: Product Name and Category Name, the second window is CategoryList and the other window is CategoryEdit, this window is a form to edit one Category.

When i save changes in CategoryEdit, all open windows has to refresh the datagrids to take the new data. What i want is, on window create, asign an event to run a custom method in each window. All window have a Refresh method, and i need to run this method of each open window every time that any window dispatch an event.

I hope I was clear, and sorry for my English

Answer (score 4):

If you use `WPF`, you need these steps to finish this task:

- create your *Products* or other data inherited from
  `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and call `OnPropertyChanged` methord.
- use `Binding` for passing your data to your `UI element`
- it is ok, if you changed one property of *Product*, your property will trigger to notify one Property changed `Like: OnPropertyChanged("Prive");`, or use `OnPropertyChanged("")` to notify all properties changed.